# How to check for empty String array including empty elements

Tags: java, arrays, apache-commons

`org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils` provides methods to check if `Array` is empty, but for example for `String` array which has empty String elementsmeaning character `""` it returns `true` for that `isNotEmpty()` method, which is correct as that method check only for `null` and `length == 0`.

Is there any other method or implementation which checks also if array has empty element ?

I could do it myself, iterate over array and manualy remove such elements of course, but I would better use any library as `apache`.

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to do it manually, perferrably using `StringUtils.isNotBlank(str)` instead of arrayUtils. So that you don't iterate twice over the array.

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8:

```
final String[] strings = {"", "Hello", "World"};
final boolean containsEmptyString = Stream.of(strings)
            .anyMatch(string -> string == null || string.isEmpty());
```

Comment: oh, its nice, but we use for now only 1.7 :(

Comment: My bad, but I can only recommend to switch! :-)

Comment: I would switch but in JavaEE most AS are not yet supporting 1.8 :(

Comment: We switched Glassfish to Wildfly and Java 7 to 8 parallel, but are a small team so less overhead.

Comment: We having IBM WAS as we are part of IBM

Answer (score 0):

So manual way is maybe only solution here in Java1.6 | 1.7 :

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String[] array){
    for(String tmp : array){
        if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(tmp)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`StringUtils` could be from apache, or own code checking for `NULL && length ==0`